# Autoshrink feature of Label in Tableview cell on scrolling doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have two labels side by side in custom cell of tableview. When I am adding data into it first time it looks like this :

[image]

which is fine and is the required design .

Problem occurs when I start scrolling the tableview. After going down in tableview and coming up it changes like this:

[image]

First label has autoshrink feature added but not in second label.  I am doing everything in storyboard except the data poulating part.
Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong in it.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT: **

The custom cell that I have added in the project:

[image]

There are two labels that I have highlighted by selecting them.

Constraints for the First Label are:

[image]

I have also added Auto Shrink feature in first label :

[image]

Constraints for the second label are:

[image]

I haven't added Auto Shrink feature in second label as I have to keep fixed font size in second label.

Comment: This question is very low quality because it does not provide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StevePiercy : I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after reading more about `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority` I got the solution.

Thanks to this blog too:

- https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real

I changed the priority as follows:

For First label:

[image]

For Second Label :

[image]

and it is working perfectly fine.